# Is the reasoning $\neg p\vee\neg q;\;p\therefore\neg q$ valid?

Tags: proof-verification, logic

> Is it valid to say that: $$\begin{array}{l}\neg p\vee\neg q\\p\\\hline\therefore\neg q\end{array}$$ knowing that?: $$\begin{array}{l}p\vee q\\\neg p\\\hline\therefore q\end{array}$$ (the last reasoning is called "Disjunctive syllogism").

---

I think yes, because:

$$\begin{array}{lll}
(1)&\neg p\vee\neg q&\text{Premise}\\
(2)&p&\text{Premise}\\
(3)&p\to\neg q&\text{Conditional equivalence in (1)}\\
(4)&\neg q&\text{Modus Ponens (2)-(3)}\\
\end{array}$$

Therefore the first reasoning is valid.

Is my deduction correct?

Comment: Everything is correct!

Comment: The "disjunctive syllogism" is a special case of [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_%28logic%29), as used (at least theoretically, implementations may differ) in Prolog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is valid. As you mention, it's called the *Disjunctive Syllogism* (or *Modus Tollendo Ponens*) and is one of the fundamental building blocks (inference rules) of propositional calculus.

The "standard" proof goes something like this, using conjunction introduction and De Morgan:

- Given $\neg p \vee \neg q$
- Given $p$
- Hypothetically suppose $q$:

  - Conjunction introduction gives $p \wedge q$
  - De Morgan gives $\neg (\neg p \vee \neg q)$
  - Let $X$ stand for $\neg p \vee \neg q$
  - We now have $X \wedge \neg X$: a contradiction
- Therefore $q \rightarrow \bot$
- Therefore, by reductio ad absurdum, $\neg q$

You can also get this without De Morgan if you have to:

- Given $\neg p \vee \neg q$
- Given $p$
- Hypothetically suppose $\neg p$:

  - Now we have $p \wedge \neg p$, which is a contradiction
- So $\neg p \rightarrow \bot$, and $\bot \rightarrow \neg q$ (principle of explosion)
- Therefore $\neg p \rightarrow \neg q$
- $\neg q \rightarrow \neg q$, by conditional introduction
- So $\neg q$ by disjunction elimination

Comment: Thank you!! Another question could be "But we did not use the disjunctive syllogism to prove the validity of this reasoning", and we could answer "But that reasoning was not necessary to prove this one", right?

Comment: @manooooh Correct! I added a short proof.

Comment: Wow, 2 different ways, awesome!! I did not understand the last part. I understand everything before $p\wedge\neg p$. I do not understand: 1) What do you mean by " everything follows from a contradiction"? 2) How do you arrive at $\neg p\to\neg q$?

Comment: @manooooh There's a rule called "ex falso sequitur quodlibet" or the "principle of explosion", which says basically that $\bot \rightarrow X$ for any $X$. I'll clarify.

Comment: Alternatively, use disjunction elimination, negation elimination, and negation introduction.$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l} #1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\small\fitch{1.~\lnot p\lor\lnot q\hspace{5ex}\text{Premise}\\2.~p\hspace{11.5ex}\text{Premise}}{\fitch{3.~q\hspace{8ex}\text{Assume}}{\fitch{4.~\lnot p\hspace{3ex}\text{Assume}}{5.~\bot\hspace{4ex}\text{Negation Elim.},2,4}\\\fitch{6.~\lnot q\hspace{3ex}\text{Assume}}{7.~\bot\hspace{4ex}\text{Negation Elim.},3,6}\\8.~\bot\hspace{7.5ex}\text{Disjunction Elim.},1,4{-}5,6{-}7}\\9.~\lnot q\hspace{10ex}\text{Negation Intro.},3{-}8}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp I didn't know one could write comments like *that*. How?

Comment: Knowing that we are in classical logic couldn't we just "go to the dual" in the first derivation by replacing "¬x" by "x" and "x" by "¬x" everywhere, which would immediately make both derivations in the original questions syntactically equivalent. Would that be appropriate?

Comment: Some what. @DavidTonhofer .  You would have to include a line applying *double negation elimination*.